# Running .net core as systemd service on ubuntu 14

Tags: linux, ubuntu-14.04, systemd, asp.net

this works fine,

```
webadmin@sandbox:/www/web/prod/prereg.example.org/prereg-sample$ dotnet restore
  Restoring packages for /www/web/prod/prereg.example.org/prereg-sample/WebApplication/WebApplication.csproj...
  Restoring packages for /www/web/prod/prereg.example.org/prereg-sample/WebApplication/WebApplication.csproj...
  Restore completed in 558.64 ms for /www/web/prod/prereg.example.org/prereg-sample/WebApplication/WebApplication.csproj.
  Lock file has not changed. Skipping lock file write. Path: /www/web/prod/prereg.example.org/prereg-sample/WebApplication/obj/project.assets.json
  Restore completed in 2.12 sec for /www/web/prod/prereg.example.org/prereg-sample/WebApplication/WebApplication.csproj.

  NuGet Config files used:
      /home/webadmin/.nuget/NuGet/NuGet.Config

  Feeds used:
      https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
webadmin@sandbox:/www/web/prod/prereg.example.org/prereg-sample$ dotnet publish
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 15.1.548.43366
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

  WebApplication -> /www/web/prod/prereg.example.org/prereg-sample/WebApplication/bin/Debug/netcoreapp1.1/WebApplication.dll
webadmin@sandbox:/www/web/prod/prereg.example.org/prereg-sample$ cd WebApplication/
webadmin@sandbox:/www/web/prod/prereg.example.org/prereg-sample/WebApplication$ dotnet run
Hosting environment: Production
Content root path: /www/web/prod/prereg.example.org/prereg-sample/WebApplication
Now listening on: http://sandbox.example.lab:5000
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
```

here is the result

```
[sandbox]/etc/systemd/system> ps aux |grep dotnet
webadmin 29736  1.2  0.5 3286936 48576 pts/4   SLl+ 13:19   0:00 dotnet run
webadmin 29775  1.5  0.5 21251244 42736 pts/4  SLl+ 13:19   0:00 dotnet exec /www/web/prod/prereg.example.org/prereg-sample/WebApplication/bin/Debug/netcoreapp1.1/WebApplication.dll
```

but when I add this to systemd which means I try to make it behave as a linux service, to be started automatically  for example.

with the following configuration

```
[Unit]
    Description=prereg application

    [Service]
    WorkingDirectory=/www/web/prod/prereg.example.org/prereg-sample/WebApplication/bin/Debug/netcoreapp1.1/
    ExecStart=/usr/bin/dotnet /www/web/prod/prereg.example.org/prereg-sample/WebApplication/bin/Debug/netcoreapp1.1/WebApplication.dll
    Restart=always
    RestartSec=10                                          # Restart service after 10 seconds if dotnet service crashes
    SyslogIdentifier=prereg-sample
    User=webadmin
    Environment=ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production

    [Install]
    WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I get this errors, do you have any ideas why does this happen?

```
[sandbox]/etc/systemd/system> systemctl start prereg-sample
[sandbox]/etc/systemd/system> systemctl status prereg-sample
prereg-sample.service - prereg application
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/prereg-sample.service; enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: start-limit) since Sat 2017-03-18 13:24:23 +04; 8s ago
  Process: 30080 ExecStart=/usr/bin/dotnet /www/web/prod/prereg.example.org/prereg-sample/WebApplication/bin/Debug/netcoreapp1.1/WebApplication.dll (code=killed, signal=ABRT)

[sandbox]/etc/systemd/system> journalctl -fu prereg-sample
-- Logs begin at Fri 2017-03-17 11:56:37 +04. --
Mar 18 13:24:23 sandbox.example.lab prereg-sample[30064]: at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScoped(ScopedCallSite scopedCallSite, ServiceProvider provider)
Mar 18 13:24:23 sandbox.example.lab prereg-sample[30064]: at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.<>c__DisplayClass16_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProvider provider)
Mar 18 13:24:23 sandbox.example.lab prereg-sample[30064]: at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
Mar 18 13:24:23 sandbox.example.lab prereg-sample[30064]: at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
Mar 18 13:24:23 sandbox.example.lab prereg-sample[30064]: at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.EnsureStartup()
Mar 18 13:24:23 sandbox.example.lab prereg-sample[30080]: Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: The configuration file 'appsettings.json' was not found and is not optional. The physical path is '/www/web/prod/prereg.example.o...ppsettings.json'.
Mar 18 13:24:23 sandbox.example.lab prereg-sample[30080]: at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileConfigurationProvider.Load(Boolean reload)
Mar 18 13:24:23 sandbox.example.lab prereg-sample[30080]: at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationRoot..ctor(IList`1 providers)
Mar 18 13:24:23 sandbox.example.lab prereg-sample[30080]: at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilder.Build()
Mar 18 13:24:23 sandbox.example.lab prereg-sample[30080]: at WebApplication.Startup..ctor(IHostingEnvironment env) in /www/web/prod/prereg.example.org/prereg-sample/WebApplication/Startup.cs:line 23
```

Answer (score 1):

I am so stupid,

```
The configuration file 'appsettings.json' was not found and is not optional.
```

means that the folder is incorrectly set, it should be /publish, the appsettings.json is there. and it worked. And the dev didn't add the config file that contains MongoDb connection string.